# name resolution ssh vs ping

Tags: ssh, nslookup

I'm having a strange problem in which for many sites if I attempt to ssh into them I get "could not resolve " as a response, but if I try ping  or nslookup  it finds the same site just fine. Is there a difference in how name resolution works between these services?

The problem is definitely related to names, I can connect to the same sites fine using the ip address rather than the name, and I can connect using the name provided I enter it into /etc/hosts (using a name I found via ping or nslookup on the same machine)

I am experiencing this on a fedora 19 machine.